# What syntax error does this sql command have?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, netbeans, embedded-database

I am trying to create a table in java embedded database ( with netbeans). I'm getting an error when executing the table creation command.
This is the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEUVz.jpg

Comment: Edit your question with your code (included in the question, not as a link) and the error message.

Comment: While creating a table or col in mysql you should avoid space and `-` if atall there is no option then you need to use `` to wrap them.

Comment: replace hyphen(-) with underscore(_) for column name, it'll work!!

Comment: thanks for so many good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the hyphen, as pointed out in the comments.  So replace it with an underscore as suggested, or simply use backticks to escape it.  So, in the create table declaration:

```
`first-one`
```

This is likely because the SQL server is interpreting the `-` as a mathematical operator 'minus'.  You will find this to be the case with all reserved words and operators which you want to use literally.  More complete information on this topic can be found here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html